# How to measure the complexity of the discrete logarithm problem?

Tags: time-complexity, discrete-mathematics, cryptography

The answers to this [question on Crypto Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/why-is-the-discrete-logarithm-problem-assumed-to-be-hard) basically says that, to measure the complexity of the logarithm problem, we have to take the length of the number representing the size of the group into account. It seems arbitrary, why don't we chose the size of the group as the argument? Is there a criterion to know what argument to chose? In fact, I know I overlooked something important since the complexity changes hugely if we do it by the size of the group.

Comment: Interesting question! I edited it to say "measure the complexity", rather than "calculate" it, since the answer to how we calculate it is ¯\\_(ツ\)_/¯. :-)

Comment: I think it's better that way. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether you choose the size of the group $|G|$ or the size of the integer representing it $n$ as a parameter, since $n \approx \log |G|$. There are two reasons that usually the complexity is described in terms of $n$ rather than $|G|$:

1. $n$ is the length of the input (more accurately, the input has length $\Theta(n)$), and we usually measure the complexity of algorithms as a function of the input length.
2. Usually $n$ is a small number such as $1024$, whereas $|G|$ is a huge number such as (roughly) $2^{1024}$.

Comment: I see your point, but doesn’t it make it a problem in P if we chose the size of the group as a parameter?

Comment: You cannot choose the parameter in that case – the parameter is always the input length.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I had a problem with what might happen if we consider the other case (problems in P becoming in NP and the other way around). I can see clearly now :) .

Comment: I wish to add something to the discussion: I still have a little issue with the problem. Suppose we have an infinite tape in which we put the integer representing the size of the group in base one (a sequence of ones) and the other stuff in binary form. Can we consider this form of the problem solvable in polynomial time since we take into account only the size of data?

Comment: Yes. This is called *unary encoding*. Factoring is also easy if the number to be factored is written in unary.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "easy", the problem is just as easy or difficult as fatoring base 2 numbers - it's just the time complexity  is low, compared to the size of the input, since we have artificially blown up the input size. I suppose it's O (n) where n is the size of the input, since we need n steps to count the 1's and figure out the number we are factoring :-)

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Then, why don't we use unary to do the calculation? Is it because of the space required or maybe because of the flexibility?

Comment: We measure the complexity of a problem in terms of the size of the inputs. If we can solve it in time polynomial in the size of the input, then we say that it is easy. This is the case for factoring a number given in unary – it can be done in time polynomial in the input.

Comment: We don't do the calculation in unary since our goal is to factor some number or to compute some discrete logarithm, and we don't care how the number is represented. Giving it as input in binary or unary doesn't affect the "wall time" needed for solving the problem, only its complexity in terms of the input size (since we are changing the input size!).

Comment: Besides, we cannot really have a 128-bit long integer as unary input to a real-world algorithm. There are not enough atoms in the universe.